# The [procedure] tag is very vague

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, burninate-tag

The [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) tag is very vague. It's been used 127 times, from taxiing to ATC to weather decisions to starting a propeller to approach procedures... the list is long. No clear "topic" or clear usage is defined.

Out of the 127 questions, only 7 are tagged with only [procedure] and no other tags ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1209144?Tag=procedure)), they are:

> 1. [In an airliner, does the Captain or the First Officer fly the airplane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5075/14897)
>      [airliner] is more applicable
> 2. [How are conflicts between pilot flying and pilot not-flying over aircraft control resolved?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5091/14897)
>      [crew-resource-management] is more applicable
> 3. [Piloting as a perishable skill - what skills go first and how to self-assess and mitigate skill loss?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8046/14897)
>      [flight-training] is more applicable
> 4. [How do pilots stay disciplined and use checklists, even after they have become routine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12205/14897)
>      [flight-training] is more applicable
> 5. [Can a runway turnpad be used as a runway holding position?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39249/14897)
>      [airport-operations] is more applicable
> 6. [What procedures exist to take control from an "unsafe" pilot?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46779/14897)
>      [crew-resource-management] is more applicable
> 7. [What notification am I required to give when starting an engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52534/14897)
>      [engine-starting] is more applicable

Note: more *more* applicable tags may exist, the point is those 7 posts do not *need* [procedure], and the volume can be retagged in two rounds 24 hours apart. I've listed them here, so if the burnination would go ahead, we can come back to those, so no question gets left behind with zero tags.

Is there any case against burnination? Is there a clear topic?

Comment: I'd agree, [tag:procedure] is a clear [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) IMO

Comment: @Jamiec: It's been over a week, with no case against burnination, how do we proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Id suggest untagging the ones tagged, and retagged the ones with only procedure. Then it will die naturally.

Comment: @Jamiec: They're now 129 posts, assuming 4 per day, that's over a month's work. Can't we get a CM on it?

Answer (score 2):

We can certainly burninate that tag. However, checking the questions that'd be left with 0 tags is not enough. Some questions may be left with tags but still, be not descriptive enough.

For example the below:

- For the [first one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53747/in-terms-of-noise-how-does-a-steep-climb-out-compare-to-a-noise-abatement-proce), it *looks* like just [noise](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) is not enough, is there something else that can be added to make it better?
- For the [second](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/do-the-cabin-announcements-follow-a-common-protocol), is [commercial-aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial-aviation) sufficient? Might benefit to be coupled with something else.

Can you please (as a community) go through the questions in the list and check&fix those cases where removing [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) would leave the question with not enough tagging? If you can remove the [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) while you're at it, that'd be great.

Comment: Hi @CesarM: [procedure] is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), not a topic, and has no clear usage. For the first example you listed, as an example, let's say we keep things as they are as a thought experiment, then what good is [procedure] doing? / Going through them manually, which will be limited to a couple per day so not to drown the homepage, would take over a month's work, assuming such action can be coordinated (*very* doubtful). IMO, the two examples here are fine w/o [procedure].

Comment: @ymb1 I agree it's a meta tag with no clear usage. No need to fix all of them, most of them should be fine without the tag - just want to make sure first that we know questions will still make sense when we mass burn the tag from existence. (Basically, what I meant is: change only the questions that will be problematic/unclear without the tag, everything else, no need to touch). In a quick scan those were the two that popped out to my (untrained in aviation) eye that might be problematic with just one tag.

Answer (score 2):

This request has been completed. [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) is burninated.

[image]

We haven't blacklisted it for now because that's an expensive process that every posted question has to go through - so let's see if the tag keeps coming back, if it does, we can blacklist it. In case of blacklisting, we also need a short blurb telling people why this is blacklisted and what to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to track progress of cleaning up the [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) tag. Use the following query to find candidate questions for retagging:

https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1232282/questions-with-procedure-tag

Those towards the top of the list have fewer tags, and should be cleaned up first

- <strike>Any tagged *only* [procedure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedure) should be retagged and procedure tag removed</strike> - completed
- <strike>Any with only 1 *other* tag might need retagging, and procedure tag removed</strike> - completed
- Any with 2 or more *other* tags which accurately tag the question do not need to be amended manually. If any manual retagging is required, procedure tag should be removed.

Please do not do more than a few per day, so as not to flood the front page, and please update here when you're done.

---

Update Log:

- 2020-04-28 - Cleared up 3 questions tagged only procedure <sub>([1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/in-an-airliner-does-the-captain-or-the-first-officer-fly-the-airplane) [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/piloting-as-a-perishable-skill-what-skills-go-first-and-how-to-self-assess-and) [3](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/how-are-conflicts-between-pilot-flying-and-pilot-not-flying-over-aircraft-contro))</sub>
- 2020-04-29 - Cleared up 3 questions tagged only procedure <sub>([4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39249/can-a-runway-turnpad-be-used-as-a-runway-holding-position) [5](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46779/what-procedures-exist-to-take-control-from-an-unsafe-pilot) [6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52534/what-notification-am-i-required-to-give-when-starting-an-engine))</sub>
- 2020-04-30 - Cleared up 3 questions with 1 other tag <sub>([7](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49795/do-the-cabin-announcements-follow-a-common-protocol) [8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51449/where-is-the-best-place-to-perform-a-run-up-at-a-busy-airport) [9](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51568/is-it-permitted-to-deviate-from-yellow-lines-during-taxi))</sub>
- 2020-05-01 - Cleared up 3 questions with 1 other tag <sub>([10](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53747/in-terms-of-noise-how-does-a-steep-climb-out-compare-to-a-noise-abatement-proce) [11](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/41015/what-is-judgemental-oversteering-in-taxi-procedures) [12](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/how-should-passengers-report-sos-signal-sightings))</sub>
- 2020-05-04 - Another 3 questions with a single other tag <sub>([13](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-is-the-procedure-to-climb-and-level-off-using-a-bendix-king-kap140-autopilo) [14](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/how-much-does-pilot-technique-affect-brake-life) [15](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/do-airlines-weigh-passengers-and-baggage-before-loading-the-aircraft))</sub>
- 2020-05-05 - Another 3 questions with a single other tag <sub>([16](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/how-do-you-enter-the-hold-after-a-missed-approach-at-riohacha-skrh) [17](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/how-is-aircraft-control-positively-transferred-between-pilot-flying-and-pilot-no) [18](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/how-to-join-a-traffic-pattern-when-passing-overhead))</sub>
- 2020-05-06 - Yet another 3 with a single other tag <sub>([19](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12707/what-is-the-difference-between-a-flow-and-a-checklist) [20](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15335/when-a-large-commercial-jet-touches-down-is-it-committed-to-stopping) [21](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16985/do-i-set-the-parking-brake-on-the-ramp))</sub>
- 2020-05-11 - And another 3  <sub>([22](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17365/should-landing-light-be-off-during-line-up-and-wait-position) [23](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/does-cargo-heat-failure-require-a-diversion-what-about-if-there-are-live-animal) [24](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25145/what-are-some-of-the-more-common-procedures-when-faced-with-a-hung-landing-gear))</sub>
- 2020-05-12 - And another 3  <sub>([25](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/how-did-this-incident-report-detailing-a-flight-taking-off-and-landing-at-glasgo) [26](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/do-companies-based-in-non-english-speaking-countries-require-intra-cockpit-proce) [27](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/purpose-of-cht-drop-in-piston-engine-shutdown-procedures))</sub>
- 2020-05-13 - 3 More today <sub>([28](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38893/does-the-da-42-automatically-lean-to-clean-fouled-spark-plugs) [29](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44031/do-concurrent-operations-on-a-single-runway-occur-anywhere-else-besides-airventu) [30](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44775/who-activates-the-fasten-seat-belt-warning-on-commercial-flights))</sub>
- 2020-05-14 - Reviewed the final 2 questions with only a single other tag <sub>([31](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65744/c-152-carb-heat-on-before-landing-in-hot-weather) [32](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75287/what-should-a-pilot-do-if-he-does-not-know-where-he-is-and-has-no-form-of-commun))</sub>

Comment: feel free to ping me here when yall are done so we can process the burnination.

Comment: @CesarM - I have now retagged anything with zero or 1 tag other than procedure, and satisfied myself that any with 2 tags remaining are ok. Could you burninate [tag:procedure] and blacklist it?

Comment: sounds good, thanks for checking that, we'll start processing soonish