# What is "burnination"?

Tags: discussion

What is "burnination"?  I have never heard this word before.

Related-- [The [procedure] tag is very vague](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/the-procedure-tag-is-very-vague)

Answer (score 2):

It's a process to delete tags (*not* the associated questions) that do not conform to the tag rules.

Recent example: [Burninate [flight]](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3941/14897)

More on MSE: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/392799)

Comment: Also, the originator of the meme: [Burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/241919)